# Outlook Web addin display Error message as information

Tags: javascript, office-js

I want to display error notification. My code is following

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("error", {
    type: "errorMessage",
    message: "The add-in failed to process this message."
})
```

it shows response as 
[image]

It should be error type message.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation on `NotificationMessages` object `.ItemNotificationMessageType` property ...

> If type is ProgressIndicator or ErrorMessage, an icon is **automatically** supplied and the message is not persistent.

This particular client (probably Web browser or desktop Outlook) displays "info" icon for `errorMessage` type of notification. If you don't like "supplied" icon you may try to use `InformationalMessage` type for your notification, which allow you to use the `icon` property. This property is the reference to an icon that is defined in the manifest in the Resources section. You should be able to use any.