# How to create a permanent notification in a new Outlook message?

Tags: outlook, add-in

([screenshot that shows WebExtNotifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKy7q.png) ) 
Is there a method to programmatically create a **permanent** notification like shown on the screenshot without "Dismiss this message" link?

If WebExtNotifications property is documented anywhere?

Thanks,
Victor Ivanidze

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes?view=vs-2017) aligned to the top. That pane is free to display anything it wants using any controls.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. As far as I understood your link describes a VSTO-based thing. My bad - I forgot to say that I'd like to manipulate  WebExtNotifications (or something similar) using Outlook JavaScript API.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to Office.NotificationMessages interface, it is returned as the notificationMessages property of an item.

For more information, Please refer to these links:

[Office.NotificationMessages interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=office-js)

[Office JavaScript API support for content and task pane add-ins in Office 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins)

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried  Office.NotificationMessages interface. Seems it can't do a permanent notification.

Comment: @Victor Ivanidze Maybe this link will help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339987/outlook-web-addin-display-error-message-as-information

Comment: Alina, I appreciate you trying to help but your link is useless. I know how to create a notification that contains "Dismsiss this message" link. My question is: how to create a notification that doesn't contain "Dismsiss this message" link?