# WebExtNotifications property is not sending with Exchange Online

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

We are trying to use
WebExtNotifications
property on an Outlook sent e-mail, similarly to what described here:
[How to create a permanent notification in a new Outlook message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477227/how-to-create-a-permanent-notification-in-a-new-outlook-message)
It works on our on-premise Exchange 2016, but not working on Exchange Online for some reason. Any reasons why? Ordinary custom properties from public strings (PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS) passing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regular named properties survive the trip, but `WebExtNotifications` does not, it could be because Exchange does not want this property to be set on the incoming messages. There are quite a few properties like that - there is a whole non-sendable range for the fixed MAPI properties, and some properties are explicitly designed to be only settable on the receiving client side, e.g. the `PR_BLOCK_STATUS` (`0x10960003`) property responsible for showing the external images.

Exchange Online is newer than your on-prem server, so it is expected it will contains extra logic like this...